# How to populate ListView from Matrix cursor

Tags: java, android

I have made a `MatrixCursor` for accessing my data. It has 4 columns. And I have a `ListView` in which each row have 3 elements (one of them is `ImageView`. So I only actually need 2 columns ). This is my first time with cursors so which adapter is best for doing this? This is my work so far.

**MatrixCursor:**

```
static MatrixCursor getnameList() {
    ArrayList<String> fsitem = getfsiList();
    String[] columnNames = {"id", "name", "info","icon"};
    MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);
    for (int i = 0; i < fsitem.size(); i++) {
        try {
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getName() + "/" + fsitem.get(i));
            if (root.canRead()) {
                File namefile = new File(root, ".name");
                FileReader namereader = new FileReader(namefile);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(namereader);
                String id = in.readLine();
                String name = in.readLine();
                String info = in.readLine();
                String[] fsii = new String[4];
                fsii[0]= id;
                fsii[1]= name;
                fsii[2]= info;
                fsii[3]= null;
                cursor.addRow(fsii);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("NameManager.java : ", ("Error!! Not Writable!!"
                    + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getName()
                    + "/" + fsitem.get(i)));
        }
    }
    Log.d("NameManager.getnameList()",cursor.toString());
    return cursor;

}
```

**row.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/list_icon" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/info"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`SimpleCursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html).
You will need a String array with the columns you want to put in the list, a int array with the ids of the `TextView` from the layout on which your adapter will bind the data from the columns. Also in order to use the cursor with the `ListView` the cursor must have a column `_id` that you add to the query:

```
String[] from = {BaseColumns._ID, "col1", "col2"};
int[] to = {R.id.Text1, R.id.text2}
SimpleCursorAdapter adap = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.the_row_layout, curosrObject, from, to);
```

**Edit:**
To implement a `_id` column in your `MatrixCursor` you could make a field in the class where you create the cursor:

```
private static int key = 0;
```

Then add another column in your `MatrixCursor` named `BaseColumns._ID`. When you will add a new row in the `MatrixCursor` add a new `Object` array instead of a `String` array, like this:

```
Object[] fsii = new Object[4];
fsii[0]= key;
fsii[1]= name;
fsii[2]= id;
fsii[3]= info;
cursor.addRow(fsii);
key++; // the _id must have unique values so increment the key value;
```

Then use the cursor like above(see small edit).

Comment: Thanks buddy, But as you can see my Cursor don't have a _id column. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class matrixCursor extends ListActivity {

    private static int key = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fillData();
    }

    private void fillData() {
        MatrixCursor matrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id","colName1","colName2" });
        String name="sethu";
        int id=1;
        String info="something";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            matrixCursor.addRow(new Object[] { key,name, info});
            key++;
        }

        String[] columnNames = {"_id","colName1","colName2" };
        int[] to = {R.id.Text1, R.id.Text2, R.id.Text3};

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.the_row_layout,
                matrixCursor, columnNames, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```